# How do I solve Chapter 3 Level 13 in See No Evil?

Tags: see-no-evil

I am trying to solve Level 13 from Chapter 3 in See No Evil, but I seem to be unable to solve it. The goal of the level seems to be to open the gates to the right (a laughing block + a screaming block).

This is what I know how to accomplish:

> - By pushing the block to `6`, then activating the switch south of `3` I have enough time to block the soundwave from the enemy above, then push the block over the "laughing blocks" at `7`.
> - I can lure the enemy at `1` to `2` by opening the "screaming blocks" and shouting upward from `3`.
> - I can shout towards `5` by standing on top of the grey blocks and shouting right.

I seem however not able to trigger the enemy west of `4` without triggering the enemy at `5` afterwards. Since I am not able to keep the "shouting stones" open for more than a few seconds, and am not able to find a pattern to repeatedly open them, I can't seem to finish this level.

An answer outlining a mechanic I am missing is preferred over an answer outlining all steps I need to take.

[image: Overview of the level with numbers describing various places]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must move 1 to 2.

Move block to 7.

About 2 seconds after 1 shout(this shout will go to 4), shout to 4(near the south edge)

Brown wall will be down twice.

Comment: I ended up with the enemy from 2 not standing in the right place. While trying to manoeuvre him. By standing at the north edge and shooting down, while the enemy shooted and I blocked the soundwave at a specific point, I got the laughing blocks to stay permanently open.